# How to save data to database in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, table

I Need to store form data to database, I follow, model/ResourceModel way,

This below my controller code: `SetData()` method not working.

```
<?php

namespace ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Controller\Profile;

 class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
protected $storeManager;
protected $subscriberFactory;
protected $_objectManager;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $customerSession);
}

/**
 * Save newsletter subscription preference action
 *
 * @return void|null
 */
public function execute()
{
    $cutomerEmail =(string)$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    if ($cutomerEmail === null) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving your subscription.'));
    } else {
        try {   

               $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
               $Format = $this->_objectManager->create('ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Model\Format');
               $Format->setCustomerid($cutomerEmail); 
               $Format->setFormat($post['type']);
               $Format->save();
              $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Profile has beem saved successfully.'));

                $this->_redirect('customer/account/');

                return;

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving your profile.'));
            }
    }
   $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
}
```

}

This is my Controller File, I defined Construct for Object manager.

My table name is "**email_format**" and its have two columns, 1.**customerid** 2. **format**,  Magento2 any other way to save data to database?, how to solve this problem?

Comment: show your model and resourceModel class

Comment: also try this  `$Format->setCustomerid($cutomerEmail);
$Format->setFormat($post['type']);`

Comment: @ Sohel Rana see this link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112550/get-form-data-to-store-database-in-magento-2    This are my module  classes

Comment: @ Amit Bera , I update my queation, I tried your way , that also not working for me. suggest me any other way to do this,  Thanks for Support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as below:

```
$Format = $this->_objectManager->create('ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Model\Format');
```

changed to:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$Format = $objectManager->create('ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Model\Format');
```

You have used `$this->_objectManager` but you have not defined it in construct.

Comment: I update my question , now, suggest me what I miss Thanks for support

Comment: Just use above code instead of `$Format = $this->_objectManager->create('ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Model\Format');`

Comment: @ Prashant Valanda I use Your code also   "$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$Format = $objectManager->create('ChennaiBox\CustomerAccount\Model\Format');" its not working for me, I think my model class probelm, This is model class link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112550/get-form-data-to-store-database-in-magento-2 suggest me what i miss in my model class.

Comment: In your code you are trying to set email address in your primary key so remove this line from your code `$Format->setCustomerid($cutomerEmail); ` and recheck it.

Comment: Yes, Now, I solved  problem. Thanks For Support.

Comment: If it helps you mark as accepted so it will useful for further.